# What is a good proverb in response to "two wrongs don't make a right"?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, proverbs

In an ideal world, I know "two wrongs do not make a right" but in the real world (or at least mine) I have often found that although they may not make a right, they often stop further "wrongs".

However, that does not stop smug third parties sometimes commenting "two wrongs don't make a right" - what would be a an appropriate proverbial response?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To provide the reference for Peter Shor's comment, now removed:

[fight fire with fire](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fight%20fire%20with%20fire)

> to fight against an opponent by using the same methods or weapons that the opponent uses

[Merriam Webster Dictionary]

Comment: Burn them! Burn them all!

Answer (score 28):

Two wrongs don't make right, **but three lefts do**.

Comment: And two Wrights make an airplane.

Comment: So, six lefts make an airplane. Good to know. Look out, Boeing, here I come.

Comment: Don't know this would actually be a good comeback in a rhetorical sense, but as for diffusing the argument and getting laughs... Well, it definitely earned a chuckle from me!

Answer (score 16):

**evil prospers when good men do nothing**

This saying appears in various forms. Here's one

> Edmund Burke, one of the foremost political speakers of 18th century
> England, said: "All that is necessary for the triumph of evil is that
> good men do nothing."
>
> https://www.crossrhythms.co.uk/articles/life/Evil_Prospers_When_Good_Men_Do_Nothing/37074/p1/

To be politically correct I suppose some would change it to, "evil prospers when good *people* do nothing"

Comment: It's a fine maxim, but doesn't imply that the something done is in itself wrong.

Answer (score 10):

I was going to say “the ends justify the means” and link to Wiktionary. That article links to “[all’s fair in love and war](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/all%27s_fair_in_love_and_war#English)”, which I like much better as a retort to “two wrongs...”

Answer (score 9):

*Leviticus* 24:19–21 has:

> “eye for an eye; tooth for a tooth”

which may be ‘appropriate’ to the poster’s purpose in some circumstances, although civilized societies are supposed to have outgrown this attitude.

(Not strictly a proverb, but biblical quotations have that kind of status. )

Comment: Do be careful, because this one has an immediate retort of "eye for an eye leaves the whole world blind" or something similar. Since we're already playing this game, this response is fairly likely.

Comment: One obvious riposte being "I'll see your *Leviticus* and raise you *Romans* 12:17–21.".

Comment: @JdeBP — I could use that as support for my final remark, but I don’t want to come over as a bible thumper.

Comment: Worth noting that "eye for an eye" is a _limitation_ on retaliation -- let the punishment fit the crime.

Comment: @AndrewAylett — Understood. It’s all coming back to me. But today it wouldn’t have that force.

Comment: [Some people](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/an-eye-for-an-eye.html) call it a proverb. And they say it was in the Code of Hammurabi, too. +1, even though I don't know of anyone who lives in a [civilized society](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/civilized), which should, according to M-W, "treat the people fairly". But it's complicated: "Though justice be thy plea, consider this: That in the course of justice none of us should see salvation."

Answer (score 5):

"Don't let the perfect be the enemy of the good", there are times where an action may be wrong but it's still the best choice you've got. An insistence upon some fanciful perfect action that realistically cannot be achieved in the circumstances - and thus doing nothing - may well make things even worse.

Comment: That's really not how that phrase is used.

Comment: @Kevin I think it is, pretty much. The action can't be completely wrong, but it is certainly non-optimal - it's just what is available right now.

Comment: @Graham "Don't let the perfect be the enemy of the good" is used to say that you shouldn't be so focused on making your product perfect that you never get it out the door when it's good enough. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_is_the_enemy_of_good

Comment: @Kevin Not just products. As the answer says, the same applies to actions you might take.

Comment: @Graham yes, but it does not mean the opposite of "two wrongs don't make a right" which is what the question is asking for

Comment: I agree with @Graham If I do a "wrong" to stop another "worse wrong", and someone tells me, TWDMAR.  A perfectly valid retort would be "I didn't want to let the perfect become the enemy of the good. Two wrongs may not make a right, but two wrongs in this case are objectively better than three or more wrongs."

Answer (score 3):

**Don't dish it out if you can't take it.**

This phrase suggests that someone who does something bad implicitly opens themselves up to having bad things done to them. Two wrongs don't make a right, but it is more acceptable to wrong someone who has wronged you. A second wrong in retaliation for a first one may not be the "right" thing to do, but the person had it coming.

If someone calls you a foul name, you could respond in kind. While someone might point out that "two wrongs don't make a right", you can justify your retort by suggesting that the person "shouldn't dish it out if they can't take it".

Answer (score -1):

Consider a specific case:  if a 'wrong' was 'damage to a ship' on the starboard side - causing said ship to list - and another, intentional but measured/controlled 'wrong' was judiciously affected to the port side such that the list was corrected, the ship 'righted', lives saved, etc. - it would be true that 'two wrongs make aright' (the ship in this case).
Is this a retort?  Not yet, but it does provide a basis for defense of the initial 'proverb' (which it is not, biblically speaking).

Like many sayings, intended meaning is dependent on the meaning as understood by the speaker (even if colloquial / common), perceived meaning as perceived by a hearer.  Only after establishing 'intended meaning' can useful dialog begin.

Answer (score -2):

In for a penny, in for a pound.

Answer (score -2):

My frequent answer to people who say this to me is, "Does your hypocrisy know no bounds?" and proceed to question their moral and ethical boundaries to determine the reasons they believed my actions were in any way wrong.

Answer (score -4):

If at first you don't succeed, try, try again.

Comment: I don't see that as a response to "two wrongs don't make a right".

Comment: No, but if they post it on enough different questions, eventually it will. Appropriate, no?

Comment: @DoublyNegative : enough different wrongs does make a right, then ?

Comment: In which case, I guess this technically does answer the question! :P